# AF-Algebras and Matrix Algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, universal-property

I have been having some trouble with an exercise from Murphy's "$C^*$-Algebras and Operator Theory" recently. Chapter 6 Exercise 6 is as follows:

If $A$ is an AF-Algebra (i.e. a direct limit of finite-dimensional $C^*$-Algebras), then so is $M_n(A)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I was thinking one would have to show that the limit and the operation turning $A$ into the matrix algebra of itself commute, maybe by setting up a map between the two spaces and showing it is a $*$-isomorphism. I am not really sure how to set this up though, and I'm also not sure if it is even enough.

I was also wondering if this statement can be generalized to any direct limit. If $A$ is a direct limit of $C^*$-Algebras, is $M_n(A)$ one as well?

---

I guess in the general case one could try verifying the universal property. Is anything simplified in the AF case? I'm not really used to proofs involving category theory or universal properties, so I was wondering if there is a reason Murphy chose to frame the exercise this way.

Comment: I think your post contains the right idea. If $A$ is the direct limit of $A_k$, then $M_n(A)$ should be the direct limit of $M_n(A_k)$. Can you build a direct system to make this precise? Show that the directed limit of this directed system is $M(A)$ by verifying the universal property.

Comment: @QuantumSpace is there a way of seeing this without using the universal property in the case of AF algebras? Or does having the direct system consist of finite dimensional algebras not actually simplify anything?

Comment: As far as I can see, the only relevant finiteness is that matrices in $M_n$ have only finitely many ($n^2$) entries.